# Improving performance with Field Collections?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using using [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference), [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) , and [field collection table](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) modules on a site that features "courses" and "lessons" as content types. A field collection with unlimited values is embedded in the course content type, and it contains two fields: a text field for "section" and an entity reference field for "lesson". This allows the same lessons to be reused in different courses, while appearing under a different section. (see screen for reference).

This works pretty well, but performance when editing course nodes starts to degrade significantly after about 30 lessons are added to a course. At 100 lessons, it takes about 15 seconds to load a course for editing. With 140 lessons in a course, it takes about 22 seconds to edit a course node. I'm testing locally on a new D7 test site with devel-generated content.

Questions:

(1) Are there any obvious steps I should take to improve performance with field collections?

(2) As an alternative to field collections, would [creating a compound field in code](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) likely improve performance significantly?

(3) For testing performance generally, is there a simple profiling tool I can use with Drupal?

Example of a small course with 10 lessons added as field collections:

[image: example of a small course with 10 lessons added as field collections]

Comment: _As an alternative to field collections, would creating a compound field in code likely improve performance significantly?_ Always depends on how much data you have, but yes, almost certainly. If you have a field collection with 5 fields, that's at least 5 db queries (or joins, if you're lucky) to get the data. With a compound field that would be reduced to a single query

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's kind of a daunting amount of code at first glance, but I guess it breaks down into smaller pieces that aren't too bad. I'll try to find time to give it a shot.

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit daunting, the field example module in [Examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples) will be very useful if you decide to go down that route

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. Lessons should have a reference to courses, not the other way around. Use a custom entity type and kill field_collection.

Comment: That's the way it is configured now on a production site. However, there is a new requirement to allow lessons to be re-used across multiple courses. Therefore, each course needs custom sections and its own sort order for lessons that belong to it. Any suggestions for how to approach?

Comment: @DaveBruns: did you figure out an alternative solution? Interesting issue.

Comment: @arjan - yes, in the end, I abandoned field collections and created a custom compound field that is attached to the 'course' content type. This pretty much eliminated the performance problems. And because the field is unlimited multivalue, the delta works a sorting mechanism for the lessons in views, etc. I also added some code to add more than one item at a time as seen here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52051/slow-add-another-item-with-unlimited-valued-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: In the end, I abandoned field collections and created a custom compound field that is attached to the 'course' content type.

This pretty much eliminated the performance problems. Opening a course node with 130 lessons in the field now takes 3-6 seconds, depending on the server.

And because the field is unlimited multivalue, the delta works a sorting mechanism for the lessons in views, etc.

I also added code to add more than one item at a time as seen here:

[Slow "Add another item" with unlimited valued fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52051/slow-add-another-item-with-unlimited-valued-fields)

When there are a lot of items in the field, adding a new item ends up taking a lot of time.

Good resources:

- http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/
- https://drupal.org/project/examples (field example)
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/7